# How can we check if a Gtk_Container is empty?

Tags: gtk

im creating a GUI with gtk 3 and don't know how to see if a Gtk_container like a gtk box for example is empty , does a function do that ? Does another manipulation can give this information ?

Thanks for the answer  .

Answer (score 1):

GtkContainer does not describe a property with the count number of children. In your application you could track this number since you are the one adding and/or removing children.

Anyway, Widgets that inherit from GtkContainer have two functions/methods that allow you to iterate by all children (w/ or w/o internal children).

Assuming the C base reference:

These are:

- [gtk_container_foreach ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-foreach)
- [gtk_container_forall ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-forall)

I believe that you will be interested in the foreach function/method as suggested by the documentation:

> Most applications should use gtk_container_foreach(), rather than
> gtk_container_forall().

You could also use the function/method [gtk_container_get_children ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-get-children)

This will return a GList with all the non internal children which you could iterate too and get a count.

Since you did not specify a language, C was assumed since it's the base reference for the Gtk framework. Nonetheless, its very easy to extrapolate to another language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this help , gratefull

Comment: I now have another time need for help , i want to clear a GtkImage in a callback function . This Callback function show an image an i want this image to be reset every time i call this callback function , any help ?

Comment: I already found the gtk_image_clear but it doesnt seams to work so do you have any tutorials on how to use it ?

Comment: I would suggest that you open a new question and give an example of problem you are having, maybe some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox));
      
for(iter = children; iter != NULL; iter = g_list_next(iter))
    gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(iter->data));
      
g_list_free(children);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.